# in flutter when build apk some warnings occurs

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

when run flutter build apk this warning occurs

Comment: `Unchecked or Unsafe Operations` : This warning is typically due to the use of raw types in your code or third-party libraries

`Deprecated API`: This warning is shown when your code or a library you’re using is calling methods that are marked as deprecated